# Hololens / Unity: recognizing the difference between Navigation and Manipulation Gestures

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm attempting to use both of the gestures below:

```
GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslate
GestureSettings.NavigationX
```

At the moment I am unable to trigger the ManipulationStartedEvent, ManipulationUpdatedEvent, etc.  It almost seems like the NavigationX events are precluding the recognition to the Manipulation.

Is this the case?  Am I misunderstanding the gesture?

Comment: I've no idea about this stuff ('hololens' and gesture 'manipulation' on it I mean) so I looked it up to find out a bit about it. Still too far :)  However, I bumped into this guy here: https://github.com/Microsoft/GalaxyExplorer/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/Input/InputRouter.cs. Unsure if it helps but I hope. Cheers

Comment: I think I am on the right track, I am using the HoloToolKit, which has a GestureManager, that has a method for transitioning between active GestureRecognizers, but still not quite there yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use Manipulation and Navigation at the same time. In the 211 course, you had to use a voice command 'Move Astronaut' to trigger Manipulation. That's because both gestures look identical to the system, so you need a trigger to distinguish between them.